# SFTP connection is getting closed by server while uploading file into SFTP n/w folder

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, azure-functions

The Sftp connection is getting closed by the server while uploading files to the sftp n/w folder. I am using C# as the programming language, and the code is deployed into an Azure function App. The file size is large(3-5 GB). It is working fine for smaller file sizes.

**I am using package- SSH.NET Version- 2020.0.1**

```
public async Task UploadFile(BlockBlobClient client, string destination)
        {
            try
            {
                using var inputStream = await client.OpenReadAsync();
                inputStream.Position = 0;
                if (!_sftpClient.IsConnected)
                {
                    _sftpClient.Connect();
                }
                _sftpClient.UploadFile(inputStream, destination);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _log.LogError("transfer failed {msg}",ex.Message);
                
            }
            finally
            {
             _sftpClient.Disconnect();
            }
    }
```

Error:

```
 Sftp file transfer failed. File:Import/test.zip Error: Connection was closed by the server.
```

Comment: Add your code here please. The info provided is too little.

Comment: I have updated the post. Let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `using` with curly braces so: `using(var inputStream = await client.OpenReadAsync()) { inputStream.Position = 0; ...... }` ?

Comment: I have used simplified using statement. Will that have any impact? I think Sftp session is getting closed during file transfer even though the connection is active. I tried a different sftp server for file transfer and it worked for a 5 GB file. Can this be an issue with the sftp server timeout configuration?